# file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1 - Server solving

Tags: php, json, ssl

I have a server online with 2 domain, both with SSL by letsencrypt

On domain A, I have created a file with json content that I can read from my pc with this code

```
$url = 'https://www.domainA.com/feed.php';

$response = file_get_contents($url, true);
$obj = json_decode($response, true);

print_r($obj);
```

When I upload this file on domainB, I get this

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in ... 
Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in ... 
Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.domainA.com/feed.php): failed to open stream: operation failed in ...
```

EDIT

Same problem with this code

```
$url = 'https://www.domainA.com/feed.php';

$arrContextOptions=array(
    "ssl"=>array(
        "verify_peer"=>false,
        "verify_peer_name"=>false,
    ),
);  

$result = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));
```

Response is

```
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in ...
```

Also with this CURL code

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($result);

$obj = json_decode($result, true);

print_r($obj);
```

i have

```
The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
```

Comment: Please avoid to use `file_get_contents` to fetch data from an API, consider using `curl`, the docs is here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: Already tried with curl, problem not solved...

Comment: Might be some error in domain resolution. Does the problem exist only with the json file or with any file on Domain A?

Comment: Ouch!!! Seems that the problem exist on domain with same server... From another server it's all ok! Sorry Man, thanks Markus :)